# Java cannot find the the String in method

Tags: java, string, static-methods

**How to correct that code?**

```
public class Solution {

    static String timeConversion(String s) {
        String sub=s.subString(0,2);         
        System.out.println(sub);
        return "test";
    }
    private static final Scanner scan = new  Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bw
                   = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String result = timeConversion(s);
        bw.write(result);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

**Solution.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        String sub=s.subString(0,2);**
  ................................................................................................^

symbol:   method subString(int,int)

location: variable s of type String

1 error

Comment: `s.substring(0,2);`

Comment: It's lower case `s` in sun**s**tring use substring instead of subString

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method for finding substring of the string is not correctly written. The correct syntax is:

input_string.substring(start_position, end_position)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use `s.substring` see the lowercase `s` after sub.